# What happens in Hopscotch Hash Tables when there are more than sizeof(Neighborhood) actual hash collisions?

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashtable, hash-collision, hopscotch-hashing

Relevant link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopscotch_hashing

Hopscotch hash tables seem great, but I haven't found an answer to this question in the literature: what happens if my neighborhood size is N and (due to malfeasance or extremely bad luck) I insert N+1 elements which all hash to the same exact value?

Comment: How odd - the original paper doesn't address this (I think it assumes you pick a different hash function?), and the implementations I've seen so far don't support this correctly.  I am very curious to hear what the proper behavior is!

Answer (score 2):

In the original [article](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~liortzaf/papers/disc2008_submission_98.pdf) it is written that table needs to be resized:

> Finally, notice that if more than a constant number of items are hashed by h into
>   a given bucket, the table needs to be resized. Luckily, as we show, for a universal
>   hash function h, the probability of this type of resize happening given H = 32 is
>   1/32!.

Comment: Yes, but even a universal hash function can have more than |H| collisions, and no amount of resizing will change the neighborhood of those collisions.

Comment: Here's solution: Maintain additional list-based hashtable and have special 'overflow' bit in "hop-information" word. Place values in additional hashtable only if there's no space in the main one and set 'overflow' bit. 'overflow' will be pretty rear case, so amortized times should be same

Comment: @jemfinch About resizing, when resizing hashtable you change number of buckets which results in new hashfunction, so chances are you won't get same number of keys in the same bucket, right?

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases where we need resize hopscotch hash

1. you have H collisions for the given bucket
2. the load factor is really too big to find the free bucket. In practice, you should setup a uplimit for search free bucket.

Given the universal hash function, you only have 1/32! chance to get into case #1, in other word, if you continuously insert 2^35 elements, then you have one chance to resize due to collisions.

The case #2 is more popular reason for resize in practice, you could refer to some quadratic implementations for how they decide to resize[C# hashmap and Google sparse hashmap], there is no real implementation for linear probe due to its cluster drawback, i.e. can't guarantee constant lookup.